# Estimating from below positive moments of "clipped" divisor function on subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,x\}$ with positive density

Tags: nt.number-theory, divisors-multiples

The question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/341686/estimating-sum-n-leq-x-n-in-a-dna-from-below-for-large-sets-a-subset) about estimating positive moments of the divisor function on sets of nonzero density $A\subset \{1,2,\ldots,x\}$ was answered giving
$$
S_a(x):=\sum_{n \in A} d(n)^a \geq |A|(\ln x)^{a(\ln 2-\delta)}\quad (1)
$$
for any $\delta>0,$ arbitrarily small.

This relies on the fact that after removing rare large values the divisor function in
$\{1,2,\ldots x\}$ is essentially of size $(\ln x)^{\ln 2}$  on average.

What if I now "clip" the divisor function at level $m=(\ln n)^{2 \ln 2}$? So consider lower bounding the sum
$$
S_{a,m}(x):=\sum_{n \in A} \left\{\max(d(n),m)\right\}^a
$$

It seems to me that this should make no difference to the lower bound in (1), but I am not sure how to make this rigorous.